# Click on Row event where there are check boxes inside that row as child elements

Tags: android, listview

I can assure I have searched and tried snippets of code to solve my problem but none seem to work as per my requirements.
I have a list view with components, the customized row is 'inflated' into the list view parent. 2 TextViews and a check box. The check boxes do react appropriately but I need to display a Toast(to make is simple for now), and to set checked the check box of that particular row.

Here is my onCreate method:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_song_selector);

    //Create the model 
    songSelectorModel = new SongSelectorModel();

    songSelectorModel.setCatalog(SongSelectorModel.getDummyCatalogData());
    listViewSongCatalog = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvCatalog);


    listViewSongCatalog.setAdapter(new CatalogListViewAdapter(songSelectorModel.getCatalog()));


    Button btnViewPlayList = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnViewPlayList);
    btnViewPlayList.setOnClickListener(new ButtonViewPlayListOnClickHandler());

}
```

And here is my getView method from the custom adapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewItem rowViewComponents;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = SongSelectorActivity.this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.song_list_item, null);
            rowViewComponents = new ViewItem();
            //TODO 02
            //Set the components of rowViewComponent from the "song_list_item" layout
            rowViewComponents.checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox01);
            rowViewComponents.textViewSongTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvSongTitle);
            rowViewComponents.textViewSongLength = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvSongLength);

            listViewSongCatalog.setOnItemClickListener(new MyOnItemClickListener());

            //Register the handlers for the buttons on the rowView
            rowViewComponents.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    int position;
                    View rowView;
                    if (isChecked) {

                        rowView = (View) buttonView;
                        position = listViewSongCatalog.getPositionForView(rowView);
                        Song selectedSong = songSelectorModel.getCatalog().get(position);
                        selectedSong.setSelected(true);
                        songSelectorModel.getPlayList().add(selectedSong);
                    } else {
                        rowView = (View) buttonView;
                        position = listViewSongCatalog.getPositionForView(rowView);
                        Song selectedSong = songSelectorModel.getCatalog().get(position);
                        selectedSong.setSelected(true);
                        songSelectorModel.getPlayList().remove(selectedSong);

                    }
                }
            });


            convertView.setTag(rowViewComponents);
        } else {
            rowViewComponents = (ViewItem) convertView.getTag();
        }


        // Get the song at the selected position from the songCatalog and 
        Song songForThisRowPosition = songCatalog.get(position);

        rowViewComponents.textViewSongTitle.setText(songForThisRowPosition.getTitle());
        rowViewComponents.textViewSongLength.setText(songForThisRowPosition.getLength() + " secs");



        return convertView;
    }
```

And finally the event handler, very basic, just a Toast to check that it is working but again, nothing happens.

```
public class MyOnItemClickListener implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {


    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Toast.makeText(SongSelectorActivity.this,"Clicked on a Row!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

I have tried different snippets where I had to set the listViewSongCatalgo.setDescendantFocusability - all three possibilities but none do give me the desired effect.
On websites other than Stackoverflow offer the same answers and still no result.
I would appreciate some insight on how to proceed.

Kind regards

Comment: try add this, listViewSongCatalog.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);, inside onCreate(). Hope that help! You may also look my samples here: http://programandroidlistview.blogspot.com/

Comment: That didn't work sorry. I have also tried setOnItemClickListener and setOnItemSelectedListener. None worked for me. :(

Comment: setOnItemClickListener should be set inside your activity, may be onCreate, but not your adapter.